# Latest post showing up as main title of page on blog page

Tags: blog-page

---

My latest blog post is showing up as the title of my blog page. I have my page set to static for the home page and have all the titles of the templates displaying at the top except the blog post. I tried to use the conditional tag "is_home" but I kept getting errors. Any help is appreciated! Here is my code at the bottom of the front-page.php

```
<?php if (is_front_page()) { ?>
<section class="m-main-hero"></section>
 <section class="m-hero-caption col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-offset-2">
  <p>Teaching kids how to eat and enjoy healthy foods through cooking cooking and experimental learning</p>
  <h2 class="subtitle fancy"><span>Since 1995</span></h2>
   </div> <!-- End of container -->
</section> <!-- end of column header -->

 <section class="m-front-img">
        <?php the_field('for_educators_image') ?>
        <figure class="m-for-families">
        </figure>
    </section>

  <?php } else if() { ?>
  <section class="m-main-hero-single"></section>
  <section class="m-single-page-header">
    <h1><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h1>
  </section>
  <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using

```
      <?php } else if(is_home()) { ?>
  <section class="m-main-hero-single"></section>
  <section class="m-single-page-header">
    <h1>Blog</h1>
  </section>
```

and it worked.